# jQuery: get the closest element by class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show and hide different elements by clicking on them.

I need to get the closest element by class name so I can later on show and hide them.

Currently I don't understand why my code doesn't find the closest element so it cannot hide or show it.

To explain this I've created this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mh211ngy/)

and this is my code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.addons',function(e){

    $(this).hide();

    $(this).closest(".newClass").show();

});
```

Could someone please advise on this issue?

Comment: There are no elements in the fiddle you linked with class "newClass".

Comment: `closest()` walks the ancestor chain of an element, starting with the element itself, but all your images are siblings.

Comment: And the full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked, not even if the link is jsFiddle. SO has Stack Snippets (the `<>` button) which are entirely up to the task of providing an [MCVE](/help/mcve) for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want `closest`, you want `next`. `closest` moves up the parents till it finds an element using that selector. `next` gets the next element in the DOM.

http://jsfiddle.net/mh211ngy/1/

<parent>
  <prev></prev>
  <**this**>
    <child></child>
  </**this**>
  <next></next>
</parent>

Comment: So, what is the opposite of next? is it prev?

Comment: Yes. I made a little diagram of it in relation to `this` above.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didn't know that i needed to use next and prev.

Comment: No problem. Happy to be able to.